# If $f'(x)\leq0$ for all $x<0$ and $f'(x)\geq0$ for all $x>0$, then is it true that $f'(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Suppose that $f'(x)\leq0$ for all $x<0$, and $f'(x)\geq0$ for all $x>0$. Then is it true that $f'(0)=0$ ? If the inequalities are strict, then I know that it is true by the intermediate property of derivative.

Comment: @ChrisCuster If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, wouldn't that make $f'$ continuous everywhere?

Comment: @ChrisCuster No - only that it has the intermediate value property, which follows from Darboux's theorem

Comment: My mistake.  Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And it is still true even if the inequalities are not strict. You can't have $f'(0)<0$ and $f'(x)\geqslant0$ when $x>0$, by the intermediate value property of the derivatives. And, by the same argument, you can't have $f'(0)>0$.

Answer (score 4):

It also follows from Mean value theorem:

$$\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = f'(h_x)$$
where $h_x$ is a real number between $x$ and $0$, and therefore, it goes to $0$ if $x$ tends to $0$. Now, if $x$ goes to zero from the positive side, $RHS$ of above equation is non-negative at each step and therefore, the limit is non-negative. Similarly it is non-positive and hence, it is zero.